# Displaying integer and float numbers in a QPlainTextEdit object

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qstring, qplaintextedit

I want to display a numerical value in a QPlainTextEdit object. I use below code for this purpose.

```
QString s;
s.sprintf("%d", deneme); //deneme is an integer value.
ui->results->setPlainText(s);
```

Is there any other method for displaying integer and float numbers in a QPlainTextEdit without defining a new QString object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QString::number()
```

You still have to create a `QString` instance (that is what `QPlainTextEdit` requires), but this may be at least a little more convenient.

There are a bunch of overloads of that method to accommodate various input and output formats.

Comment: `ui->results->setPlainText(QString::number(deneme));` Does this code also create a QString object or not?

Comment: Yes; you can't get around the creation of a QString--that is what the `setPlainText` method requires. The usage above (probably) creates a temporary, and the compiler *might* optimize this away, but there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
ui->results->setPlainText(QString("%1").arg(deneme));
```